# Django allauth - SocialTokens table empty after Google Login

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

- Python:       3.8.10
- Django:       4.1.7
- django-allauth:   0.54.0

I'm working on a webpage which I have to connect to the Company Google Workspace.
I correctly managed the login, with no issues.
Now, I have to connect to the Gmail of the authenticated user.

For connecting to Google Apps I need a Token that, as I understood, should be in the Database in the table SocialTokens (automatically filled-in after the login phase).

I populated Sites and Social Application manually, and rightly (I guess) based on fact that login works.

The authentication works properly, but after the login the model SocialToken (table "Social application tokens") is still empty.

But I cannot figure out why the table SocialTokens is not populated after the correct Google login.

Here my **settings.py**

```
SITE_ID = 1

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...,
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
]

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google':{
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'access_type':'offline'},
    }
}

SOCIALACCOUNT_STORE_TOKEN = True

SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = True
```

I tried what below:

- update django-allauth (0.4 --> 0.54)
- SOCIALACCOUNT_STORE_TOKEN = True --> set False, True and unset(commented and deleted)
- SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = True --> set False, True and unset(commented and deleted)
- two lines above in all their combinations (es. SOCIALACCOUNT_STORE_TOKEN = True and SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = False, viceversa, etc...)
- after each change I flushed the db, recreate superuser and redo the login with Google(which has properly worked)
- I checked Google API Client_id and Secret, if any value was wrong or wrongly set (on https://console.cloud.google.com/)
- tested both SITE_ID = 1 and 2, after have created a new Site
- tested 'access_type':'offline' and 'online'(also if it is wrong based on documentation usage of SOCIALACCOUNT_STORE_TOKEN)
- with and without https (in case it affects the data transmission, local and public)
- DEBUG = True and False

Could anyone tell me if I wrote something wrong or if I missed anything, or if I misunderstood anything?

Thanks for any help.